# Building a responsive image grid

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm building a responsive image grid using the following code:

```
.gallery {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0 40px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 33%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    background-color: #093;
}

.boxInner {
       position: absolute;
       left: 5px;
       right: 5px;
       top: 5px;
       bottom: 5px;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
    .boxInner img {
       width: 100%;
    }
    .boxInner .titleBox {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       margin-bottom: -50px;
       background: #000;
       background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       color: #FFF;
       padding: 10px;
       text-align: center;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
       transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }

<section class='gallery'><div class='box'>
      <div class='boxInner'>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery-1" href='http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/?attachment_id=202'><img src="http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Club-Soda-400x260.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Club Soda" /></a>
      </div></div><div class='box'>
      <div class='boxInner'>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery-1" href='http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/?attachment_id=233'><img src="http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Main-Room-400x260.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Main Room" /></a>
      </div></div><div class='box'>
      <div class='boxInner'>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery-1" href='http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/?attachment_id=232'><img src="http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Upstairs-Arena-400x260.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Upstairs Arena" /></a>
      </div></div><div class='box'>
      <div class='boxInner'>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery-1" href='http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/?attachment_id=231'><img src="http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/The-Gallery-400x260.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="The Gallery" /></a>
      </div></div><div class='box'>
      <div class='boxInner'>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery-1" href='http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/homepage/reception-2/'><img src="http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Reception-400x260.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Reception" /></a>
      </div></div><div class='box'>
      <div class='boxInner'>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery-1" href='http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/?attachment_id=230'><img src="http://ng1club.everythingcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/The-Terrace-400x260.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="The Terrace" /></a>
      </div></div>
  </section>
```

However its leaving a gap on the right but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Its most likely something simple but I can't figure it out:

Heres a JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wMNNB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things I can see:

1. You have width 100% and padding of 5px.  That means it's going to be 100% + 10 pixels as wide as the container.  You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` in modern browsers to use a box moden that does not include padding when determining width.
2. You are using 33% width.  That leaves 1% with 3 elements.  Try 33.3334%.

Comment: Great that was it!!!! Cant believe adding the .3334% solved it!!!! I was already using the box-sizing in my main site. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding padding and using inexact values (`33%`), it won't align properly. You can solve the padding problem with: ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMNNB/1/))

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This makes width include the padding (and border).